# Java 8: Can we use map to make an instance method ref in a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to refactor some of my code to Java 8. Is it possible to make an instance method ref to a method that takes 2 params with map method in streams? Below is my code.

```
for (SubjectAreaMappings pageFromEnum : SubjectAreaMappings.values()) {
    if (page.equals(pageFromEnum.toString())) {
        for (SubjectAreaCode subjectAreaCode : pageFromEnum.getCodes()) {
            list.addAll(areaDAO.getData(context, subjectAreaCode));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to refactor the inner `for` loop to something like the following code, but is it `map()` that I should be using or `reduce()`? How can I pass the 2 params `context` and `subjectAreaCode`?

```
Arrays.asList(pageFromEnum.getCode()).stream().map(somethng wrt method ref here).collect(toList())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduce()` is not an alternative to `map()`. It is an alternative to `collect()`. In your example you are collecting the processed elements to a `List`, so you should use `collect()`.

You cannot pass explicit parameters to method references. Therefore you should use a lambda expression in this scenario:

```
Arrays.asList(pageFromEnum.getCodes()).stream().map(code -> areaDAO.getData(context, code)).collect(toList());
```

BTW, your `Stream` pipeline seems to only replace the inner for loop. You could write a `Stream` pipeline to replace both the outer and inner loops:

```
list = 
    Arrays.stream(SubjectAreaMappings.values())
          .filter(s -> page.equals(s.toString()))
          .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.getCodes())
                              .map(code -> areaDAO.getData(context, code)))
          .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! One question. So can we use `reduce()` when we are trying to count/sum or things like that?

Comment: @user3310115 Yes, you can, but usually it's easier to map the Stream into an IntStream and use its built-in `count()` and `sum()` methods.

Comment: Also I didn't use `stream()` on `SubjectAreaMapping.values()` because I couldn't find a `stream()` method on it. `SubjectAreaMapping` is an enum. so `.values()` returns `SubjectAreaMapping[]`. So I'm doing something like this now. `Arrays.asList(ReportSubjectAreaMappings.values()).stream()......` is this ok?

Comment: @user3310115 You can use `Arrays.stream()`.

Comment: one last question. What if the inner list returns a list `getData()`. Is there a replacement for `allAll()`?

Comment: @user3310115 In that case you can use a second flatMap : change `.map(code -> areaDAO.getData(context, code))` to `.flatMap(code -> areaDAO.getData(context, code).stream())`

Comment: For readability I think it is better to move additional stream operations outside the lambda that is passed to `flatMap()`, and continue with the initial stream like this: `… .flatMap( s -> Arrays.stream(s.getCodes()) ) .map(code -> areaDAO.getData(context, code))`

Comment: Since `areaDAO.getData` doesn’t refer to `s`, there is no need to have the mapping step nested inside the other lambda. It’s only a matter of changing the place of one `)`, but allows to get rid of the extra indentation, which makes the code more readable imho.

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.stream(SubjectAreaMappings.values())`, you can write `EnumSet.allOf(SubjectAreaMappings.class).stream()` which saves the temporary array creation, but usually, `enum`s have only a few constants, so it doesn’t make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little shorter code by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
StreamEx.of(subjectAreaMappings.values())
        .filter(p -> page.equals(p.toString()))
        .flatMap(p -> StreamEx.of(p.getCodes()))
        .flatMap(c -> StreamEx.of(areaDAO.getData(context, c)))
        .toList();
```

if `areaDAO.getData` is a database access, it's a good example to use parallel stream here:

```
StreamEx.of(subjectAreaMappings.values())
        .filter(p -> page.equals(p.toString()))
        .flatMap(p -> StreamEx.of(p.getCodes()))
        .parallel()
        .flatMap(c -> StreamEx.of(areaDAO.getData(context, c)))
        .toList();
```